# Broadleaf Commerce Heat Clinic admin page replace logo

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Heat Clinic's admin page displays broadleaf logo which I need to change to some other logo .

How can that be done ? I know from the docs that all the html templates are in the WEB-INF/templates folder of the site module of the DemoSite project but after going through all the templates there is no mention of the broadleaf logo .

I did find the relative path of the logo image from the source code of the admin page but there is no such path present in my eclipse workspace .

It seems the html of the admin page is referencing an external file from the local file system out side the eclipse  workspace .

Can any one please help me on this . I have searched a lot but it did not help . Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change broadleaf logo inside admin's page header, put your logo inside your project's admin/src/main/resources/open_admin_style/img/admin/. Rename your logo's name to "blc-logo-header.png".

This will change admin page header's logo to your logo.

For changing logo on admin login page, put your logo to the same path as mentioned above, and rename it to "blc-logo-150.png", this will change logo on login page.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the [`header.html`](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/bcd28749d2f649af1283732c505640ab2f7e56f7/admin/broadleaf-open-admin-platform/src/main/resources/open_admin_style/templates/layout/partials/header.html) template from the open admin platform.

Instructions how to do it can be found [here](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/admin-customization-tutorials/customizing-admin-templates).

Comment: I am using DemoSite project and donot have header.html file . This file is available in the full broadleaf commerce framework . Can You please tell me how to change the logo using the framework code . I did import the blc framework code but the build of the integration module failed so I cannot run it .   @Indronil Chaudhuri

Comment: The .html file is included in one of the broadleaf jar files. You don't need to  edit it directly, but override it using the instructions I posted above.